# Seting value of a property for an item causes NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

Basically what I am trying to do is add a customer in a customer list, in the customer list there is a property  BillToContact. I would like to create an instance BillToContact for a customer.

```
public class Customer 
{
    public string  ID { get; set; }
    public string  AccountName { get; set; }
    public Contact BillToContact { get; set; }
}

public class BillToContact
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

// Below is attempt to add BillToContact to Customer

```
public void test()
{
  List<Customer> Customer = new List<Customer>();

  Customer x = new Customer();
  x.ID   = "MyId";
  x.AccountName = "HelloAccount";
  x.BillToContact.FirstName = "Jim";
  x.BillToContact.LastName  = "Bob";

  Customer.Add(x);
}
```

The error for this attempt was an

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have also tried to create a instance of `BillToContact` inside of `Customer` to no success. To avoid any confusion, The issue is that I am trying to make a instance if BillToContact inside the Customer list.

Comment: Should have been duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it... But have nice answer...

Comment: It's  not the same question, the context of mine is different

Comment: I assume you've carefully read the answer to linked question and compared "Indirect" sample to your code. It would make your question significantly better if you'd link to that question and clearly explained what steps you've taken to debug and how your case is completely different

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to instantiate the property member before you can set its properties:

```
Customer x = new Customer();
x.ID   = "MyId";
x.AccountName = "HelloAccount";
x.BillToContact = new BillToContact();
x.BillToContact.FirstName = "Jim";
x.BillToContact.LastName  = "Bob";
```

Just instantiating the parent class does not automatically instantiate any *composed* classes (unless you do so in the constructor).

Answer (score 8):

You need to instantiate the BillToContact

So either:

```
x.BillToContact = new BillToContact {FirstName = "Jim", LastName="Bob"};
```

or

```
 x.BillToContact = new BillToContact();
 x.BillToContact.FirstName = "Jim";
 x.BillToContact.LastName = "Bob";
```

Both are equivilent

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other answers are correct in that the object needs to be instantiated, but I have spotted a quirk with your code. It's not necessary to create a separate class called `BillToContact` considering it shares exactly the same properties as the `Contact` class. If you need `BillToContact` to have more properties in addition to those already in the `Contact` class, you could perform inheritance by making `BillToContact` a sub-class of `Contact`.

In addition, you can even make a constructor call from within the default constructor for `Customer`, so that way you can immediately assign values as per my example below by knowing the object won't be null:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public string  ID { get; set; }
    public string  AccountName { get; set; }
    public Contact BillToContact { get; set; }

    //Contructor
    public Customer()
    {
        //Instantiate BillToContact 
        BillToContact = new Contact();
    }
}

Customer x = new Customer();
x.ID = "MyId";
x.AccountName = "HelloAccount";

//This would now work because BillToContact has been instantiated from within the constructor of the Customer class
x.BillToContact.FirstName = "Jim";
x.BillToContact.LastName  = "Bob";

Customer.Add(x);
```

Alternatively, you could also create a constructor for the `Contact` class and have it accept the first name and last names as parameters. This way you can create a new `Contact` object and populate both the first name and last name in one hit, see below:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Contact() {}

    public Contact(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }
}

Customer x = new Customer();
x.ID = "MyId";
x.AccountName = "HelloAccount";
x.BillToContact = new Contact("Jim", "Bob");
Customer.Add(x);
```

Comment: Side note: consider joining http://codereview.stackexchange.com - suggestions to improve code are more appropriate/appreciated there... much less on SO. There is also unfortunately no "extended comment" type of post which your answer essentially is.